# My GTA 4 social club is not opening

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

So I recently installed GTA IV on my computer i did the online activate and then tried to start it (with the LaunchGTAIV.exe) and it said this.

[image: What is this???]

How do I fix this? Oh and I tried reinstalling The social club, so don't bother asking if i did so.

Comment: Which version of the game is this? Boxed or steam?

Comment: Boxed i just purchashed it 3 days ago

Answer (score 2):

You may need to download [GFWL](http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/Live/PC/DownloadClient). Even though GFWL isn't used anymore, some older games like GTA 4 required it alongside the Social Club. Worth a shot.

Comment: I tried to start GFWL it just opens and closes and for your information i don't have mac i have windows 8.1 these are my pc specs. Acer Aspire 5349 32-bit 4gb ram Intel HD Graphics family and processor Celeron 1.60GHz

Comment: @OG7Mas You can't run the game with Intel HD Graphics.

Comment: Yeah, you need a better card. Minimum specs are: 256MB Nvidia 7900 / 256MB ATI X1900

Comment: By the way... its woeking fine now even though my card is Intel HD its 500mb graphics memory man